# Decorating drawn arrows in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to define a custom command which is to be an arrow with a tilde (`\sim`) on top of it.

So far I have

```
\newcommand{\tosim}{\mathrel{%
  \tikz[baseline,label/.style={%
      postaction={%
        decorate,transform shape,
        decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with \node {$\sim$};}
      }
  }]
    \draw[-stealth,label={[above]}] (0ex,0.56ex) -- (3ex,.56ex);}}
```

With this the node sits right on top of the middle of the arrow. I would like it to be above by a certain amount. I've tried `above=2ex` and `yshift=2x` in various places, but either the file doesn't compile, or there's no scalable shift. Where should I use `above=` and where `yshift=` (and which is better for this situation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `raise=<amount>` for decorations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\newcommand{\tosim}{\mathrel{%
  \tikz[baseline,label/.style={%
      postaction={%
        decorate,transform shape,
        decoration={markings,raise=.2cm,mark=at position .5 with \node {$\sim$};}
      }
  }]
    \draw[-stealth,label={[above]}] (0ex,0.56ex) -- (3ex,.56ex);}}

\begin{document}
$\tosim$
\end{document}
```

[image]